# Communication between Activity and Service to change Fragments(Login)

Tags: java, android, service, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have `LoginActivity` that displays the Login Fragment initially . Now when the user fill the data and press login button I send the credentials to an `IntentService` . before the service hit the server it sends a local broad cast intent  to the `LoginActivity` to display the Loading Fragment (replace the login fragment) . If the login process successfully terminated it send a broadcast intent to the `LoginActivity` to  start the  `MainActivity` , and if it fails it send a broadcast intent to the `LoginActivity` to display the Error Fragment .

Now I am doing things the right way ? what about having this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1341)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1352)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
```

? I thing this  error will happened , now how can i handle the FragmentTransaction in the onReceive() method where i change Fragments in the Login Activity.

is there a better architecture  to handle the login using `Activity` and `IntentService`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use commitAllowingStateLoss()  instead of commit().

Edited:

The problem is that you call commit after the onSavedInstanceState method. You have to unregister the reciever when the activity is not in the front (in onPause())Check out this comment stackoverflow.com/a/18306939/1333170

Comment: Btw why do you use IntentService for performing login to your app? IntentService is designed for long running operations. Wouldn't be better to use AsyncTask?